# What is the difference between rowsBetween and rangeBetween?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

From the PySpark docs [`rangeBetween`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=rangebetween#pyspark.sql.WindowSpec.rangeBetween):

> `rangeBetween(start, end)`
>
> Defines the frame boundaries, from start (inclusive) to end (inclusive).
>
> Both start and end are relative from the current row. For example, “0” means “current row”, while “-1” means one off before the current row, and “5” means the five off after the current row.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - start – boundary start, inclusive. The frame is unbounded if this is -sys.maxsize (or lower).
> - end – boundary end, inclusive. The frame is unbounded if this is sys.maxsize (or higher).
>     New in version 1.4.

while [`rowsBetween`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=rowsbetween#pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween)

> `rowsBetween(start, end)`
>
> Defines the frame boundaries, from start (inclusive) to end (inclusive).
>
> Both start and end are relative positions from the current row. For example, “0” means “current row”, while “-1” means the row before the current row, and “5” means the fifth row after the current row.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - start – boundary start, inclusive. The frame is unbounded if this is -sys.maxsize (or lower).
> - end – boundary end, inclusive. The frame is unbounded if this is sys.maxsize (or higher).
>     New in version 1.4.

For `rangeBetween` how is "1 off" different from "1 row", for example?

Comment: Found a good explanation here: https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/

Comment: updated PySpark docs - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#window

Answer (score 59):

It is simple:

- `ROWS BETWEEN` doesn't care about the exact values. It cares only about the order of rows, and takes fixed number of preceding and following rows when computing frame.
- `RANGE BETWEEN` considers values when computing frame.

Let's use an example using two window definitions:

- `ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 2  PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`
- `ORDER BY x RANGE BETWEEN 2  PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

and data as

```
+---+
|  x|
+---+
| 10|
| 20|
| 30|
| 31|
+---+
```

Assuming the current row is the one with value 31 for the first window following rows will be included (current one, and two preceding):

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|  x|ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 2  PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW|
+---+----------------------------------------------------+
| 10|                                               false|
| 20|                                                true|
| 30|                                                true|
| 31|                                                true|
+---+----------------------------------------------------+
```

and for the second one following (current one, and all preceding where x >= 31 - 2):

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  x|ORDER BY x RANGE BETWEEN 2  PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 10|                                                false|
| 20|                                                false|
| 30|                                                 true|
| 31|                                                 true|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I am not following the RANGE BETWEEN example. Can you please elaborate, specifically on the "x >= 31 - 2".

Comment: Here, x needs to be greater than or equal to the range. Range = Highest_Number - Lowest_number. In this example, range = 31-2 = 29.

Answer (score 15):

The Java spark docs add clarity: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/WindowSpec.html#rowsBetween-long-long-

**rangeBetween**

A range-based boundary is based on the actual value of the ORDER BY expression(s). An offset is used to alter the value of the ORDER BY expression, for instance if the current order by expression has a value of 10 and the lower bound offset is -3, the resulting lower bound for the current row will be 10 - 3 = 7. This however puts a number of constraints on the ORDER BY expressions: there can be only one expression and this expression must have a numerical data type. An exception can be made when the offset is unbounded, because no value modification is needed, in this case multiple and non-numeric ORDER BY expression are allowed.

**rowBetween**

A row based boundary is based on the position of the row within the partition. An offset indicates the number of rows above or below the current row, the frame for the current row starts or ends. For instance, given a row based sliding frame with a lower bound offset of -1 and a upper bound offset of +2. The frame for row with index 5 would range from index 4 to index 6.

Answer (score 11):

**rowsBetween: - With rowsBetween you define a boundary frame of rows to calculate, which frame is calculated independently.**

**Frame in rowsBetween does not depend on orderBy clause.**

```
df = spark.read.csv(r'C:\Users\akashSaini\Desktop\TT.csv',inferSchema =True, header=True).na.drop()
w =Window.partitionBy('DEPARTMENT').orderBy('SALARY').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn('RowsBetween', F.sum(df.SALARY).over(w)).show()


first_name|Department|Salary|RowsBetween|

 Sofia|     Sales| 20000| 20000|
Gordon|     Sales| 25000| 45000|
Gracie|     Sales| 25000| 70000|
Cellie|     Sales| 25000| 95000|
Jervis|     Sales| 30000|125000|
 Akash|  Analysis| 30000| 30000|
Richard|   Account| 12000| 12000|
 Joelly|   Account| 15000| 27000|
Carmiae|   Account| 15000| 42000|
    Bob|   Account| 20000| 62000|
  Gally|   Account| 28000| 90000
```

**rangeBetween: - With rangeBetween, you define a boundary frame of rows to calculate, which may change.**

**Frame in rangeBetween depends on orderBy clause. rangeBetween will include all the rows which has same value in orderBy clause like Gordon, Gracie and Cellie have same salary so included with the current frame.**

**For more understanding see below example: -**

```
df = spark.read.csv(r'C:\Users\asaini28.EAD\Desktop\TT.csv',inferSchema =True, header=True).na.drop()
w =Window.partitionBy('DEPARTMENT').orderBy('SALARY').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn('RangeBetween', F.sum(df.SALARY).over(w)).select('first_name','Department','Salary','Test').show()

 first_name|Department|Salary|RangeBetween|
  Sofia|     Sales| 20000| 20000|
 Gordon|     Sales| 25000| 95000|
 Gracie|     Sales| 25000| 95000|
 Cellie|     Sales| 25000| 95000|
 Jervis|     Sales| 30000|125000|
  Akash|  Analysis| 30000| 30000|
Richard|   Account| 12000| 12000|
 Joelly|   Account| 15000| 42000|
Carmiae|   Account| 15000| 42000|
    Bob|   Account| 20000| 62000|
  Gally|   Account| 28000| 90000|
```

Comment: You state both that `Frame in rowsBetween does not depend on orderBy clause.` and `Frame in rowsBetween depends on orderBy clause.`. Something is wrong.

Comment: Changed. See now

Answer (score 1):

RANGEbetween looks at the ORDER BY clause to determine if a row is included in a window.

ROWSbetween looks at the order of the rows.

RANGE between checks if the ORDER BY is within some specified range, and will include them in a window.

ROWSbetween will form your window based on what rows are positionally around your current row (irregardless of the value of the ORDER BY column for those rows)