# rangeBetween with negative values for previous rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use a window which calculates the mean of the last 5 results before the current result.

For example, if I have a dataframe with results, the `mean_last_5` would be as follows:

```
   Result    Mean_last_5
1. 4         NaN
2. 2         NaN
3. 6         NaN
4. 3         NaN
5. 2         NaN
6. 6         3.4
7. 3         3.8
```

The 6th row would be calculated as: `(4+2+6+3+2)/5 = 3.4`.

So in pandas terms, I would a rolling window of 5 with an shift of 1.

With PySpark I just can't figure out how to do this. Current code:

```
def mean_last_5(df):
    window = Window.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('year').rangeBetween(Window.currentRow-5, Window.currentRow)

    return df.withColumn('mean_last_5', sf.avg('result').over(window))
```

Error:

> cannot resolve due to data type mismatch: A range window frame with value boundaries cannot be used in a window specification with multiple order by expressions:

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't care about the values in the rows, only the offset to the currently row, you should use `rowsBetween` instead of `rangeBetween`. The difference is illustrated here: [What is the difference between rowsBetween and rangeBetween?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048919/what-is-the-difference-between-rowsbetween-and-rangebetween).

Note that for `rowsBetween` both values are inclusive, so to get the rolling mean for the previous 5 rows (not including the current one) you want to define the window as:

```
window = Window.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('year').rowsBetween(Window.currentRow-5, Window.currentRow-1)
```

or similarly:

```
window = Window.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('year').rowsBetween(-5, -1)
```

Then use it as before:

```
df.withColumn('mean_last_5', avg('result').over(window))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def mean_last_5(df):
    window = Window.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('year').rangeBetween(-1, -6)

    return df.withColumn('mean_last_5', sf.avg('result').over(window))
```

I've put 0 because I want the current row and -5 because I want the 5 previous including the actual result.

Comment: Note that from the question example the current row should *not* be used in the calculation.